# Is there a Pytorch counterpart of the book Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading?

Tags: machine-learning

As a beginner in fintech, I am reading the book Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading by Stefan Jansen. I think it is a really helpful book. But most of the codes are written in tensorflow 2.

I want to learn Pytorch, I would like to know that if there is a book as good as this one and with codes written in Pytorch?

Comment: Welcome to QSE. I don't know a book I am afraid but your question reminded me of a brilliant [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUmRQCC61Vw&t=623s) and I couldn't resist sharing it.

Comment: As someone who started with Tensorflow and then switched to Pytorch, I can say that the official site helped a lot https://pytorch.org/tutorials/ and also browsing through some Github repos.

Comment: @user34031 Thank you very much! Could you please share me some links of the github repos?

Comment: @user900476 I cannot, this was more of a general tip. But GitHubs search bar works great :)